# Module.export-ing a New Instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

If I attach an object to the `module.exports` object in node like so:

```
module.exports = new Object()
```

will each `object = require('./Object')` throughout my application create a new instance of that object, or will it create a reference to the one instance?

Comment: If you want a new instance for each use, it's probably worth making each create their own instance. `module.exports = Object;` then `var Object = require('./Object'), object = new Object();`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`require()` caches files that it executes.

The first time you `require('./Object')`, it will run your code and place the exported object in `require.cache`.
Subsequent calls will return the cached object immediately.

You could remove your module from the cache yourself, or use a getter, but those are bad ideas.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to look into require.cache. The idea is that I'm going to be requiring this object in many places throughout my application, and I want to do it in such a way that there's as little overhead as possible.

Comment: @ConnorBlack, could it be simpler?  If you only ever need one instance, an object literal might be enough: `module.exports = { ... }`

Comment: Thanks, I like that syntax

Answer (score 1):

Check out [caching caveats](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) in the node docs.  You'll get the same object as long as the resolved module path matches.  There's an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13577906/407845) of when resolved paths would not match.